# getmac address returns blank if disconnected from the internet

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

I am trying to get the mac address of my clients computer which works fine if the computer is connected to the internet, but as soon as the computer disconnect from the internet the Mac Address returns blank.

Any Idea why and if there is any reliable function I can use, as the windows getmac which I run from the command line returns the mac address all the time regardless of it is connected to the internet or not.
Is there anyway I can call the getmac function using delphi.

I use this code

```
function GetMACAdress: string;
var
  NCB: PNCB;
  Adapter: PAdapterStatus;

  URetCode: PChar;
  RetCode: char;
  I: integer;
  Lenum: PlanaEnum;
  _SystemID: string;
  TMPSTR: string;
begin
  Result    := '';
  _SystemID := '';
  Getmem(NCB, SizeOf(TNCB));
  Fillchar(NCB^, SizeOf(TNCB), 0);

  Getmem(Lenum, SizeOf(TLanaEnum));
  Fillchar(Lenum^, SizeOf(TLanaEnum), 0);

  Getmem(Adapter, SizeOf(TAdapterStatus));
  Fillchar(Adapter^, SizeOf(TAdapterStatus), 0);

  Lenum.Length    := chr(0);
  NCB.ncb_command := chr(NCBENUM);
  NCB.ncb_buffer  := Pointer(Lenum);
  NCB.ncb_length  := SizeOf(Lenum);
  RetCode         := Netbios(NCB);

  i := 0;
  repeat
    Fillchar(NCB^, SizeOf(TNCB), 0);
    Ncb.ncb_command  := chr(NCBRESET);
    Ncb.ncb_lana_num := lenum.lana[I];
    RetCode          := Netbios(Ncb);

    Fillchar(NCB^, SizeOf(TNCB), 0);
    Ncb.ncb_command  := chr(NCBASTAT);
    Ncb.ncb_lana_num := lenum.lana[I];
    // Must be 16
    Ncb.ncb_callname := '*               ';

    Ncb.ncb_buffer := Pointer(Adapter);

    Ncb.ncb_length := SizeOf(TAdapterStatus);
    RetCode        := Netbios(Ncb);
    //---- calc _systemId from mac-address[2-5] XOR mac-address[1]...
    if (RetCode = chr(0)) or (RetCode = chr(6)) then
    begin
      _SystemId := IntToHex(Ord(Adapter.adapter_address[0]), 2) + '-' +
        IntToHex(Ord(Adapter.adapter_address[1]), 2) + '-' +
        IntToHex(Ord(Adapter.adapter_address[2]), 2) + '-' +
        IntToHex(Ord(Adapter.adapter_address[3]), 2) + '-' +
        IntToHex(Ord(Adapter.adapter_address[4]), 2) + '-' +
        IntToHex(Ord(Adapter.adapter_address[5]), 2);
    end;
    Inc(i);
  until (I >= Ord(Lenum.Length)) or (_SystemID <> '00-00-00-00-00-00');
  FreeMem(NCB);
  FreeMem(Adapter);
  FreeMem(Lenum);
  GetMacAdress := _SystemID;
end;
```

Comment: http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=651

Comment: FWIW, dynamic allocation here is an anti pattern. Declare variables of the appropriate types and use `@` to take their addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use NetBios.  Use [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917().aspx) or [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx) instead.  Also keep in mind that a machine may have multiple network adapters installed, and thus have multiple MAC addresses available.

Comment: Hi Remy, thank your for your reply but do you have an example I can use please, I found another code but it's the same thing on some computers if not connected to the internet it returns blank Mac Address.

Comment: The two links I provided show you exactly how to use the functions. Just translate them to Delphi, not that difficult. In any case, network adapters do not have to be connected to a network in order to have a MAC.  Both `GetAdaptersInfo()` and `GetAdaptersAddresses()` provide the MAC addresses for installed adapters whether they are connected to any networks or not.